# Direct3D 12 STATE_CREATION ERROR #649: CREATE_CONSTANT_BUFFER_VIEW_INVALID_RESOURCE

Tags: c++, directx, directx12

Every time my constant buffer helper creates the "Constant buffer view" with the `CreateConstantBufferView` method i get an error which states:

**D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Device::CreateConstantBufferView: pDesc->BufferLocation 0x00000000a9df6000 does not belong to any existing Resource or Heap. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #649: CREATE_CONSTANT_BUFFER_VIEW_INVALID_RESOURCE]**

this makes no sense as the resource is created and used (just like in the previous **working** usages of this method) the only thing that is different is the descriptor heap and obviously the instance of the constant buffer helper.

Also it is used by a different command list and Pipeline state object (PSO), this may be the problem but I am unsure.

here is the relevant code for the creation of the constant buffer view:

```
D3D12_CONSTANT_BUFFER_VIEW_DESC desc = {};
desc.BufferLocation = cbvGpuAddress;
desc.SizeInBytes = size;
m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice()->CreateConstantBufferView(&desc, cbvCpuHandle);
sizeInBytes = desc.SizeInBytes;
```

Below is for the creation of the descriptor heap and constant buffer helper:

```
 m_cbvSrvHeapManager = std::make_shared<DescriptorHeapManager>(DX::c_frameCount + 1, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_SHADER_VISIBLE, m_deviceResources);
    m_cbvDescriptorSize = m_cbvSrvHeapManager->GetDescriptorSize();

m_mvpConstantBufferManager = std::make_unique<ConstantBufferManager<Structures::ModelViewProjectionConstantBuffer>>(DX::c_frameCount, m_mvpConstantBufferManager->GetAlignedSize(), m_deviceResources, m_commandListManager);
    for (int n = 0; n < DX::c_frameCount; n++)
    {
        m_mvpConstantBufferManager->CreateBufferDesc(m_mvpConstantBufferManager->GetAlignedSize(), n, m_cbvSrvHeapManager, m_cbvDescriptorSize);

    }
```

Below is for the previous **working** usage of the creation of the descriptor heap and and constant buffer helper:

```
m_cbvSrvHeapManager = std::make_shared<DescriptorHeapManager>(DX::c_frameCount + 2, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_SHADER_VISIBLE, m_deviceResources);

m_cbvDescriptorSize = m_cbvSrvHeapManager->GetDescriptorSize();
    m_mvpConstantBufferManager = std::make_unique<ConstantBufferManager<Structures::ModelViewProjectionConstantBuffer>>(DX::c_frameCount, m_mvpConstantBufferManager->GetAlignedSize(), m_deviceResources, m_commandListManager);
for (int n = 0; n < DX::c_frameCount; n++)
{
    m_mvpConstantBufferManager->CreateBufferDesc(m_mvpConstantBufferManager->GetAlignedSize(), n + 2, m_cbvSrvHeapManager, m_cbvDescriptorSize);
}
```

Comment: You've got a lot of bespoke classes/methods being used here, so I don't think we can debug your problem for you from this. Note that you should take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started), and in particular the ``GraphicsMemory`` and ``LinearAllocator`` classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some how i fixed it, i created the vertex and index buffers **after** the constant buffers.

Comment: Don't forget to come back here in a couple of days and mark this as answered :)